# Flask CSV streaming randomly gets cut off?

Tags: heroku, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

My CSV is just a simple query pulled from the database (SQLAlchemy). For large files >5000 lines, the CSV stream sometimes quits around 3000 or 4000 lines.

My app is on Heroku, which has 30 second timeout, but I don't think that applies to downloading files as well.

Comment: So can you explain more that what is your problem?

Comment: @mehdy I explained the problem above. The CSV stream for the same 5000+ row CSV is stopping around 3000-4000 randomly only sometimes. Other times it will download the correct number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason could be two parameters!

1) first the timeout that you mentioned it.

2) second it may be the body request size limitation.

so check your web server configuration and try to change the timeout and body request size limitation.